# Как послать запрос на сервер

Tags: php, json

Установил себе Postman.
В теле запроса такое

```
{
        "apiKey": "[ВАШ КЛЮЧ]",
        "modelName": "TrackingDocument",
        "calledMethod": "getStatusDocuments",
        "methodProperties": {
            "Documents": [
                {
                    "DocumentNumber": "20400120240053"
                }
            ]
        }

    }
```

В ссылке такое

```
http://testapi.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/en/documentsTracking/json/
```

Получаю ответ

```
{
        "success": true,
        "data": [
            {
                "Number": "20400120240053",
                "Redelivery": 0,
    . так далеее....
```

Копирую ctrl+c ctrl+v ответ в файлик в формате json ( response.json)
И обрабатываю его так

```
<?php
            $jsondata = file_get_contents("response.json");
            $json = json_decode($jsondata,true);

            //$output = $json['data'];
            foreach ($json['data'] as $data) {
                $output .= "Номер декларації: ".$data['Number']."<br/>";
                $output .= "Місто відправки: ".$data['CitySender']."<br/>";
                $output .= "Склад відправки: ".$data['WarehouseSender']."<br/>";
                $output .= "Місто отримання: ".$data['CityRecipient']."<br/>";
                $output .= "Склад отримання: ".$data['WarehouseRecipient']."<br/>";
            }
            echo $output;
             ?>
```

На фронтенде получаю.
Номер декларації: 20400120240053
Місто відправки: Дніпро
Склад відправки: Відділення №6: вул. Ударників, 27
Місто отримання: Ковель
Склад отримання: Відділення №1: вул. Володимирська, 135

Как мне послать этот запрос.
Я так понимаю из input я буду брать номер декларации
как его вставлять динамически в запрос.
И как потом ответ помещать в файл?
Если кто может напишите пример....
Буду очень признателен.

Comment: а зачем php? если можно обойтись фронтедном... воспользуйтесь ajax запросом (какраз вставьте необходимые данные с инпутов), при получении ответа обработайте его. Все это делается в js

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц не нам с вами диктовать как НУЖНО решать задачу ТС

Answer (score 0):

POST-запрос, с json-данными в качестве параметра запроса можно отправить с использованием ф-ции [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
<?php
$payload = <<< EOT
{
    "apiKey": "[ВАШ КЛЮЧ]",
    "modelName": "TrackingDocument",
    "calledMethod": "getStatusDocuments",
    "methodProperties": {
        "Documents": [
            {
                "DocumentNumber": "20400120240053"
            }
        ]
    }
}
EOT;
$opts = [
    'http' => [
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $payload
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$jsondata = file_get_contents(
    "http://testapi.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/en/documentsTracking/json/",
    false,
    $context
); // <--- результат!

...
```

Полученный результат - данные в json-формате.

Можно, вместо ф-ции [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php) использовать библиотеку [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php):

```
<?php
$payload = <<< EOT
{
    "apiKey": "[ВАШ КЛЮЧ]",
    "modelName": "TrackingDocument",
    "calledMethod": "getStatusDocuments",
    "methodProperties": {
        "Documents": [
            {
                "DocumentNumber": "20400120240053"
            }
        ]
    }
}
EOT;
$ch = curl_init("http://testapi.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/en/documentsTracking/json/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
]);
$jsondata = curl_exec($ch); // <--- результат!
curl_close($ch);
```

Полученный результат - данные в json-формате.